# what package remote repository to use from tunisia and how can I configure my texmaker?

Tags: texlive

what package remote repository to use from tunisia and how can I configure my texmaker ?

Answer (score 1):

From Tunisia any mirror in Europe should be fine. Otherwise use one of the mirrors in Africa, that is:

- Algeria (http://ctan.epst-tlemcen.dz/tex-archive/)
- South Africa

  - http://ctan.mirror.ac.za/
  - http://ftp.leg.uct.ac.za/pub/packages/ctan/
  - http://ftp.sun.ac.za/ftp/CTAN/

Not sure which one is the best.

Concerning TeXmaker: you simply need to make sure that the TeX executables are found by adjusting the PATH environment variable.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understood your question properly.  By "remote repository" I assume you would like to figure out where to go to download the ingredients to run texmaker.

Download [texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html)

You then need a TeX distribution.  I am partial to [texlive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html).

Follow the texlive "Quick Install", this has always worked well for me.

Comment: I think OP has MikTeX and wants to choose the appropriate mirror in the menu.

Comment: @percusse how did you figure that out from her question.  Do you run MikTeX yourself?

Comment: Just guessing as it asks pretty often when installing a package.

Comment: There is so much LaTeX here, and out there, that I had no idea of what MikTeX (and plain TeX)  was until I had been using both LyX and LaTeX for at a least a couple of years.  I'm in midst of learning some plain tex and know some of it works in latex, is the same true with MikTeX, can you salt some MikTeX into your latex?